# How can I migrate from C++ XE3 to XE7 with FireDAC?

Tags: c++, postgresql, firedac, c++builder-xe3, c++builder-xe7

I have an app writen in C++ Bulder XE3 and now i want to upgrate to XE7. But I use FireDAC for connection with PostgreSQL and in XE3 the connection is called ADConnection and query ADQuery and in XE7 FDConnection and FDQuery.
I what to find an easy way to do so, without rewrite everything.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation is an article that explains everything in detail what you have to do:
[Migrate AnyDAC to FireDAC](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Migrating_AnyDAC_Applications_to_FireDAC).
In short, there is a tool 'refind' that comes with the installer of XE7 and does the conversion for all the 'AD'-components to 'FD'-components.
I did this for several programs, and it works really good, almost no manual work has to be done.

Comment: Can I use in the same time XE3 and XE7? I don't know if i have budget for upgrade for both my computer. (one is with xe3 and the other one is new, so it is xe7)

Comment: You can use XE3 and XE7 next to each other (I do that too), but once you migrated the code from ADAC to FDAC, your project won't compile any longer on XE3.